# Why does ProvideAspects method not add the attribute to IL when instantiating it?

Tags: c#, postsharp

I have the following code for an attribute i'm applying to a class and a property within the class:

```
public class SerialiseAttribute : Attribute, IAspectProvider, IValidableAnnotation {

    public string ApplyToProperty { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public bool Ignore { get; set; }

    bool IValidableAnnotation.CompileTimeValidate(object target) { return true; }

    IEnumerable<AspectInstance> IAspectProvider.ProvideAspects(object targetElement) {
        var type = targetElement as Type;

        if (type != null && !FastSerialisationCacheAttribute.AppliedTo.Contains(type)) {
            FastSerialisationCacheAttribute.AppliedTo.Add(type);
            yield return new AspectInstance(type, new FastSerialisationCacheAttribute());
        }
    }

}
```

This intialises the FastSerialisationCacheAttribute and executes CompileTimeInitialize successfully (it derives from the TypeLevelAspect aspect).  However, when I check the IL generated; there is no FastSerialisationCacheAttribute on the type provided, nor at runtime can I find one using reflection.

If I switch out the ProviderAspects function with this code:

```
IEnumerable<AspectInstance> IAspectProvider.ProvideAspects(object targetElement) {
    var type = targetElement as Type;

    if (type != null && !FastSerialisationCacheAttribute.AppliedTo.Contains(type)) {
        FastSerialisationCacheAttribute.AppliedTo.Add(type);
        var constructor = typeof(FastSerialisationCacheAttribute).GetConstructor(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public, null, Type.EmptyTypes, null);
        var objectConstruction = new ObjectConstruction(constructor);
        var introduceCacheAspect = new CustomAttributeIntroductionAspect(objectConstruction);
        yield return new AspectInstance(type, introduceCacheAspect);
    }
}
```

Then it adds the attribute to IL, but this doesn't initialise the attribute (execute CompileTimeInitialize).

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think you're already really close to a solution in your question. If you want to introduce both aspect and attribute dynamically then you need to return instances of both `FastSerialisationCacheAttribute` and `CustomAttributeIntroductionAspect` from `ProvideAspects` method.

The method `IAspectProvider.ProvideAspects` is executed **after** all the previously applied aspect attributes have been read from the assembly. If you introduce another attribute in the second example then it's already too late for it to cause aspect introduction.

In `IAspectProvider.ProvideAspects` you would normally introduce additional aspects to the target. If you really need to also introduce the actual attribute, then you would use `CustomAttributeIntroductionAspect`.

Note that adding the attribute is normally not needed for the aspect to work, but I don't know what is the logic in your code.